# ASP.NET MVC Global.asax Injection with Spring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, global-asax, spring.net

I'm trying to inject a property into my SpringMvcApplication (from [Spring.Web.Mvc](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc.html)).

```
public class MvcApplication : SpringMvcApplication
{
    public ISomeService SomeService { get; set; }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use SomeService
    }
}
```

Then I have a Services.xml file which contains my definitions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <object name="HttpApplicationConfigurer" type="Spring.Context.Support.HttpApplicationConfigurer, Spring.Web">
    <property name="ApplicationTemplate">
      <object>
        <property name="SomeService" ref="ISomeService" />
      </object>
    </property>
  </object>
  <object id="ISomeService" type="WebProject.Services.SomeService, WebProject">
    <constructor-arg ref="UserService" />
  </object>
</objects>
```

Whenever I try to use the SomeService property, I get a null reference exception. Is my configuration wrong? Do I need any additional configuration?

My workaround for now that doesn't seem proper is this

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContext()
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContext();

    SomeService = (ISomeService)ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("ISomeService");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MvcApplication extends the SpringMvcApplication class, which actually *sets up the Spring.net context*, so to me it looks kind of strange to use di to configure its properties.

The method you are overriding now is intended to allow you to make last second changes to the Spring.net application context, just before it is passed to the asp.net mvc infrastructure.

In your case, a slightly better workaround would be to have SomeService access the context directly in its getter. This way you'd have the advantage of Spring managed object scopes, which you don't have now.

Comment: I'm only overriding that method now because I was unsure of how to get a reference to my service. So instead of following the guidance in [this post](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=5378) by Erich Eichinger, you recommend putting some logic in my getter? When you say access the context directly, do you mean by using `Context.GetContext()` like I have in my overridden method? Sorry if that's a silly question, I've never used Spring before.

Comment: Not a silly question at all ... I'm merely suggesting an improvement over your existing workaround, but it should still be considered a workaround. note that the post you are referring to seems to concern the classic asp.net support and I'm not sure it holds for spring mvc.

Comment: Yes, I mean using Context.GetContext like above. But this is something you should generally avoid, so please consider this an improved workaround instead of a definite solution.

Comment: Cool. I'll stick with this until I can find something that isn't a workaround. Thanks.